# Eigen with EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I compiled my C++ project(using Eigen 3.2.8) with the EIGEN_USE_BLAS option and link against MKL-BLAS, every thing works fine and that indeed speeds up my program substantially(perhaps due to a lot of complex-valued matrix-vector multiplication)

Then I also tried the EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL, however, some similar errors prompt up:

```
/eigen3/Eigen/src/QR/ColPivHouseholderQR_MKL.h:94:1 error:
Cannot convert "Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::matrix<int,-1,1>>::Scalar*
{aka int*}" to "long long int*" in initialization
EIGEN_MKL_OR_COLPIV(...)
```

Two questions here:

1. EIGEN_USE_BLAS enables a 4x speed up though I didn't expect that much, possible reason?
2. EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL seems to have some type conflict with LAPACK stuff, how to fix the compiling error?

Comment: Are you using MKL with ILP64 interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. MKL utilizes new [AVX/AVX2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#CPUs_with_AVX) instruction set (8 32-bit `float` operations per clock with FMA and 3-operand instructions), while Eigen 3.2.8 only supports up to [SSE4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) (4 32-bit `float` operations per clock). As indicated by ggael, you could update to 3.3beta1 to achieve better performance.
2. You could try Eigen 3.3-beta1. Currently I cannot reproduce your problem. You may want to provide your code sample and compile option. But based on your error message, I guess you are using ILP64 interface, which is [not supported by Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html). You could use LP64 instead.

Answer (score 4):

To complete kangshiyin answer, Eigen 3.3 supports AVX/FMA and can thus achieve similar performance. You need to compile with AVX and FMA instructions enabled. For instance with GCC, clang, or ICC: `-mavx -mfma`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, what about question 2?

Comment: I think kangshiyin was correct about LP64 interface.